# Python Keep points in spline interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, spline

I wrote a code that performs a spline interpolation:

```
x1 = [ 0., 13.99576991, 27.99153981, 41.98730972, 55.98307963, 69.97884954, 83.97461944, 97.97038935, 111.9661593, 125.9619292, 139.9576991, 153.953469 ]
y1 = [ 1., 0.88675318, 0.67899118, 0.50012243, 0.35737022, 0.27081293, 0.18486778, 0.11043095, 0.08582272, 0.04946131, 0.04285015, 0.02901567]

x = np.array(x1) 
y = np.array(y1)

# Interpolate the data using a cubic spline to "new_length" samples
new_length = 50
new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length)
new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(new_x)
```

But in the new dataset generated  `new_x` and `new_y` the original points are eliminated, only the first and the last values are kept. I would like to keep the original points.

Comment: why dont you do then `new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(x)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, `linspace` won't generate any of the values in `x` except the ones you pass to it (`x.min()` and `x.max()`).

I don't have a great snappy answer, but here is one way to do it:

```
# Interpolate the data using a cubic spline to "new_length" samples
new_length = 50
interpolated_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length - len(x) + 2)
new_x = np.sort(np.append(interpolated_x, x[1:-1]))  # include the original points
new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(new_x)
```

This code uses:

- `np.linspace` to create as many extra points as we need
- `np.append` to combine the array of extra points with the original points from `x`
- `np.sort` to put the combined array in order

Answer (score 0):

If your data is uniform, this is another way:

```
import numpy as np

def interpolate_add(x_add,num):
    x_add_ls=[]
    for i in range(x_add.shape[0]-1):
        x_add_ls += (np.linspace(x_add[i],x_add[i+1],num+2)[0:-1]).tolist()
    x_add_ls.append(x[-1])    
    return np.array(x_add_ls)

x=np.linspace(1,5,5)
print(x)
print(interpolate_add(x,3))
```

it prints：

**[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]**

**[1.  1.5 2.  2.5 3.  3.5 4.  4.5 5. ]**

In the code, `interpolate_add` have two parameters

- `x_add` is your data(numpy.array). Data shape is (N,)
- `num` is the insert data number between two original data.

For example, if your data is `array([1, 3])` and the `num` is 1, the result is `array([1, 2, 3])`